# How to check if date format(dd/mm/yyyy) is correct in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, date

I have made a program that sort dates and displays them year-wise. 0+years, 10+years, 20+years, etc. I have also validated the date. For example, there should be no more than 31 or less than 1 days. I also have validation for leap years, months etc. How do I check if format of date is valid or not? I want to should show an error message that the date format is incorrect on inputting date as 6/7/2008 or 6/07/2008. The format should be dd/mm/yyyy.

```
Person People::getPerson()
    {
        Person person;
        Validation validate;
        string input;
        bool ch;
        int memNo = 0;

        cout << " \nEnter another Person\n" << "Membership Number: ";
        cin >> memNo;
        person.SetMemNo(memNo);
        //While the input entered is not an integer, prompt the user to enter an integer.
        while(cin.fail())

        {
            cin.clear();

            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');


            cout << "Invalid data. Please type an integer! " << endl;
            cout << "Membership Number: ";
                cin >> memNo;

                cout << endl;




        }


        cout << "Enter first name of person: ";
        cin >> input;
        bool onlystring = validate.IsDigitsOnly(input);

                  //validate string for only alphabets,no                                                                           numbers

            if (onlystring == true) {
                cout << "Enter only alphabets for first name" << endl;
                cout << "Enter first name of person: ";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore();
                cin >> input;
            }

        person.SetFirstName(input);

        cout << "Enter your Surname ";
        cin >> input;
        person.SetLastName(input);
        bool onlystring1 = validate.IsDigitsOnly(input);          //validate string for only alphabets,no                                                                       numbers

            if (onlystring1 == true) {
                cout << "Enter only alphabets for last name" << endl;
                cout << "Enter your Surname ";
                cin >> input;
            }
            bool valid_date = false;
            do {
                cout << "Enter your date of joining(DD/MM/YYYY): ";
                cin >> input;


                string new_date= validate.checkFormat(input);
                valid_date = validate.valDate(new_date);
                if (valid_date == true)
                    person.SetDateJoined(new_date);

                else 
                    cout << "Invalid Date!Please  re-enter date of joining!" << endl;


            } while(valid_date == false);
```

date validation

```
bool Validation::valDate(string input)
{
    int Y = stoi(input.substr(6));
    int M = stoi(input.substr(3, 2));
    int D = stoi(input.substr(0, 2));
    //check year
    if (Y >= 1900 && Y <= 9999)
    {
        //check month
        if (M >= 1 && M <= 12)
        {
            //check days
            if ((D >= 1 && D <= 31) && (M == 1 || M == 3 || M == 5 || M == 7 || M == 8 || M == 10 || M == 12)) {

                return true;
            }
            else if ((D >= 1 && D <= 30) && (M == 4 || M == 6 || M == 9 || M == 11)) {

                return true;
            }
            else if ((D >= 1 && D <= 28) && (M == 2)) {

                return true;
            }
            else if (D == 29 && M == 2 && (Y % 400 == 0 || (Y % 4 == 0 && Y % 100 != 0))) {

                return true;
            }
            else {

                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Year is not valid.\n");
        return false;
    }

    return 0;
}


int Validation::Prepend_function ( int n) {
    if (n < 10 && n < 0) {
        string num = to_string(n);
        string new_num = "0" + num;
        int number = stoi(new_num);
        return number;

    }
    else {
        return n;
    }
}



string Validation::checkFormat(string input)

{

    //check the length of the string

    int len = input.size();

    if (len != 10)

    {
        int year = stoi(input.substr(4));
        int month = stoi(input.substr(2, 1));
        int day = stoi(input.substr(0, 1));

        int prepend_day = Prepend_function(day);
        int prepend_month = Prepend_function(month);
        string day1 = to_string(prepend_day);

        string month1 = to_string(prepend_month);
        string year1 = to_string(year);
        string date = day1+"/"+month1+"/"+year1;
        return date;

    }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us your codes.

Comment: ok,I posted the code right now

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.  You don't need `People` or `Person` for that, and it appears that your member can be a simple function.  Also, you appear to missing several `#include` lines and a `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to implement `Validation::checkFormat`, because `Validation::valDate` doesn't seem incorrect.

```
std::string Validation::checkFormat(std::string input)
{
    std::stringstream in(input);
    int day, month, year;
    char ignore;
  // Match num/num/num, otherwise invalid
    if (in >> day >> ignore >> month >> ignore >> year)
    {
        std::stringstream out;
      // Force leading 0s
        out << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << day << '/' << month << '/' <<  std::setw(4) << year;
        return out.str();
    }

  // have to return something if it isn't valid
    return std::string();
}
```

Note that `checkFormat` sounds to be the wrong name for returning a string formatted in a particular way. I would call it `fixFormat`, and compare `input` to the result of `fixFormat`. If they are the same, then `input` is in the specified format